# Node.JS NPM not working on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I just installed the latest version of nodejs, and while I can get it to run js files just fine, I can't get npm to do anything.

If I open the node.exe, it brings up a prompt, then I separately tried each of the following and none of them work:

```
> node npm install socket.io
> npm install socket.io
> help
> node help
```

ALL of the above result in nothing but the line "..." to be returned, then every thing I type in after that, I just get another line of "...".

This is extremely frustrating. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I saw the same thing when I first tried `npm` after installing node. Just now I've tried it again and it is working. I have rebooted in the meantime but can't be sure that's what made the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening node.exe will bring up the Read–eval–print loop (REPL). Try just:

```
c:\users\windowslogin>npm install socket.io
```

Comment: holy crap. I can't believe I didn't try that! haha. It feels like I had tried everything else. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I bet I did the same thing last time and the right thing this time! (-:

Answer (score 5):

If you had command prompt open whilst installing the latest nodejs then the path to npm in windows path will not be recognised until you close the command prompt and open a new one.

I know this already has an accepted answer but I just found this and then realised my own mistake and thought it might help someone else.