# NPM isn't working on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, npm

I have installed Node.js on windows with the installer and tried running the npm command but it won't run.
When I typed in the following.

```
npm install socket.io
```

I got this

```
module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

When i typed

```
npm
```

I got this

```
module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

I checked and I have the npm-cli.js file in the right spot. How do i get the npm command to work. Do I need to set an enviormental variable to the npm-cli.js file? If I do, can you lead me througgh the process?

Comment: What does "it won't run" mean? Is anything happening? Do you get an error message? Did you search here first to read things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505723/node-js-npm-not-working-on-windows) to see if they apply? You're giving absolutely no information here that can be used to try and help you. Please edit your question and provide more details, and remember that we can't see your screen from here - the only information we have is what you give us in your question. Thanks.

Comment: It gives me an error message saying the module can't be found but if I type in node npm-cli.js the nmp runs but it doesn't allow me to pass it parameter

Comment: As I said, **please edit your question and provide more details**. You'll find the edit link directly below the tags you assigned, if you're logged in under the same account that posted the question. Adding details in the comments makes them harder for people trying to help you to locate; they belong in the original question. Thanks. :) (Also, did you check the link I posted to see if it helped?)

Comment: *Why* do you have node_modules in C:\Windows\System32? For starters: it's a stupid place to put it. For second: 32/64-bit filesystem redirection is probably getting your way. Just install nodejs with the default settings, and node_modules should be somewhere under C:\Users\PacoDev\AppData.

Comment: That is were node installed it to. Wait node isnt installed their its installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add NodeJS and NPM to my system variables.